# Is there a way to use EC2 as backend for iOS app developed on Monaca?

Tags: ios, cordova, amazon-ec2, onsen-ui, monaca

We created a webapp (all code is on EC2 server) and now, we are trying to create an iOS app using Monaca, which is based on OnsenUI/Cordova.

We would like to use Monaca for the "front-end" and leave EC2 as the "back-end". What would be the best way going about this? Apologize for the loose language, we're novices. Any guidance, suggestions, and etc. are **GREATLY APPRECIATED**.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create and expose a webservice endpoint with methods that handle your requests. In my apps I create a WCF service using C# in Visual Studio then I call the exposed methods using jQuery ajax or JavaScript's XMLHttpRequest(). You also need to allow CORS on the server.